# Why does the column show up at the end of the dataframe instead of the front?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has the following columns:

```
person_id   useless_1   useless_2   imp_1   ...   imp_58   useless_3   useless_4
```

I only want a dataframe with `person_id` and the `imp` columns.
But when I try:

```
df=(df.iloc[:,:1])+(df.iloc[:,3:59])
```

I get the desired df, but the `person_id` comes at the end, after all the `imp` columns. Why does this happen? Is there any way to bring it to the front?

Sorry for the trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) is more appropiate here, since you can filter by column name, and order is preserved:

```
df.filter(regex=(r'person_id|^imp'))
```

---

Checking with an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['person_id', 'useless_1', 'useless_2', 'imp_1', 'imp_58'])
df.filter(regex=(r'person_id|^imp'))
# person_id, imp_1, imp_58
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on your logics

```
df[df.columns[:1].append(df.columns[3:])]
```

Or

```
df.drop(df.columns[2:4], axis=1)
```